# How to clean non Arabic letters from a text file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

UPDATE-
Very new to python,
How to clean the text from everything but Arabic letters. I used regex function but without success.

This is my code

```
# load text
filename = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/ArabicKidsStories.txt'
file = open(filename,'rt')
text = file.read()
file.close()
import re
text = re.sub('([@A-Za-z0-9_]+)|[^\w\s]|#|http\S+', '', text) # cleaning up
print (text)
```

This is a sample of the output

```
 تفقدت نظارتي  حين استيقظت صباحا  فلم أجدها في مكانها  وبحثت عنها في كل مكان  دون أن أعثر لها على أثر  يا إلهي  كيف سأخرج اليوم من البيت  وأواجه النهار  
 وتناهى إلي من الخارج  صوت نقار الخشب  فوق جذع شجرة قريبة فأسرعت إلى الباب  وفتحته  وإذا ضوء النهار يبهر بصري  فأغلقت عيني  وهتفت  أيها النقار  أين أنت  
 وحاولت عبثا أن أفتح عيني  وأنا أقول  عفوا  لا أستطيع أن أفتح عيني  إن الضوء يعميني  
 فقال نقار الخشب  هذا طبيعي  يا عزيزتي  فأنت لم تضعي نظارتك الشمسية  
 وتراجعت قليلا  وقلت  لقد اختفت نظارتي  
 فتساءل نقار الخشب  اختفت  ماذا تقولين  
 وبدل أن أجيبه  قلت  أرجوك  ابحث لي عن نظارتي  إنني لا أستطيع الخروج من دونها  
 ولاذ نقار الخشب لحظة  ثم قال  حسن  ابقي أنت في البيت  وسأبحث لك أنا عنها  
 ومضى نقار الخشب  فأغلقت الباب والنافذة  وقبعت في الظلام  يا للغرابة  إنني أرى في الليل أيضا  أوه  كلا  إنني أحب النهار  وأحبذ أن أطير دوما في النور مع رفاقي  إنني لا أحب الليل  ولا أريد أن يكون الظلام عالمي  ترى أين اختفت هذه النظارة اللعينة  
    
 ـــــــــــــ 
 عاد نقار الخشب متعبا  قبل المساء  وقال لي  آسف  يا عزيزي  سألت عن نظارتك الطيور جميعا  لكن أحدا منهم لم يرها  
 فأطرقت برأسي برهة  ثم قلت  أشكرك  يا عزيزي  سأبحث عنها بنفسي ليلا  
 واتسعت عينا نقار الخشب دهشة  وقال  ليلا  
 وقبل أن أجيبه  مضى على عجل  وهو يقول  عفوا  صغاري ينتظرونني الآن  إلى اللقاء
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems with your regular expression. First, the "@" symbol must be in the [range], not outside. Second, you have a wrong type of dash between 0 and 9. Here is a corrected expression. It works:

```
'([@A-Za-z0-9_ـــــــــــــ]+)|[^\w\s]|#|http\S+'
```

Comment: Thanks this works, but still, there are underscores in the text, how to delete them?

Comment: They are not underscores, they are something else. I added that symbol to the regular expression, even though I do not know its name and purpose.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is still stuck on cleaning an Arabic dataset refer to this documentation [enter link description here](https://pyarabic.readthedocs.io/ar/latest/features.html) to filter out non-Arabic words:

```
from pyarabic.araby import tokenize, is_arabicrange, strip_tashkeel
text = u"اسمٌ الكلبِ في اللغةِ الإنجليزية Dog واسمُ الحمارِ Donky"
tokenize(text, conditions=is_arabicrange, morphs=strip_tashkeel)
#result: ['اسم', 'الكلب', 'في', 'اللغة', 'الإنجليزية', 'واسم', 'الحمار']
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you. You want just to clean non-arabic chars (so chars like **1 @ ?** gonna not be deleted).

If you want another char to be deleted just add it to **charsotdelete**.

If you have any questions let me know.

```
charstodelete = 'azertyuiopqsdfghjklmwxcvbn'
filename = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/ArabicKidsStories.txt'
file = open(filename,'r')
text = file.read()
file.close()
output_text = ''

# It's all about this
for char in text:
    if char in charstodelete or char in chartodelete.upper():
        continue
    else:
        output_text += char


outputfile = open('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/output.txt','w')
outputfile.write(output_text)
outputfile.close()
```

**EDIT:** Reg Ex are a bit of pain to get use to them if you are a beginner as you said. I recommend to use a code like that instead of Reg Ex

Comment: Thank you, but using a regex is a requirement, and I need to remove everything but Arabic letters even the extra white spaces between lines.. appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
text = re.sub('[a-zA-Z0-9_]|#|http\S+', '', text)
```

I just remove the [^\w\s] and it removes all alphanumeric underscores without removing the Arabic text

Comment: Thank you, but this leaves the Html tags and I want to remove everything but the Arabic letters

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to remove non-Arabic characters we can find Arabic characters by their character codes. The [Arabic unicode block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_(Unicode_block)) is codes from `0x0600` - `0x06ff`.

Here that is as regular expression to find all of the words:

```py
import re

arabic_words = re.findall('[\u0600-\u06ff]+', input_text)

print(arabic_words)
```

The expression here is using a character range with one or more (the `+`). This should give you a list of the words.

If the text above is arranged into sentences you could so something similar after splitting the text appropriately to get the sentences together.